# Flexbox - screen splitting on small screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have found an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exBJLw) on Codepen which splits the screen in two halves.

How to make the example divide the screen vertically when the height is smaller than the width? I want to utilize the screen area on small devices better, because in my opinion a narrow long rectangle looks worse than a nearly square rectangle.

```
.leftside, .rightside {
height:50vh;
width:100%;
color:#fff;
font-size:40px;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px)
{
.leftside, .rightside {
    height:100vh;
}
}
```

[image: horizontal]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with aspect-ratio -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/aspect-ratio

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 5px solid green;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.container>.leftside {
  background: red;
}

.container>.rightside {
  background: blue;
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/8) {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
  }
  .container>div {
    height: 50vh;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftside">left</div>
  <div class="rightside">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing code snippet and for pointing in right direction! In the end, I used `(orientation: landscape/portrait)`.

Comment: yes, you are right. Landscape/portrait is perfect for your task. I know it, but i didn't thought at it. :)

Comment: @microspace i forgot to give the .container a height of 100%. I changed this now.