# Canvas game doesn't fit to parent div while resizing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, phaser-framework

I have a Phaser game, which is placed in flexbox div element. When I resize page, flex-flow switch from `column` to `row` mode. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434994/1402321) is what I used as example.
In that example rezising works as expected.

Somehow container of Phaser game doesn't resize in the save way.
Here is gif example[image]
 In the gif you can see that width of game doesn't restore when I increase screen width.

Here is live [demo](https://microspace.github.io/game010.html)
Source code is [here](https://github.com/microspace/microspace.github.io)

Comment: Do you expect both sides to be 50% all the time?

Comment: @microspace It's working but slow I think it's a caching problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container has the `flex` but your inner divs don't have any rule that enforce the ratio between the 2 divs.
in order to enforce 1:1 ratio use this for both divs

```
.container>div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    height: 50vh;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

or a shorthand (doesn't work on IE)

```
flex: 1 0 50%;
```

Without it, the browser can change the ratio according to the content of each div - will give more space for a div with a "bigger/wider" content.